# How to align a div centered-below another while keeping them separate divs

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS and trying to center a div below another. I want them to be separate divs but I can't get it to work despite trying several suggestions such as using: relative, absolute, etc. The first div contains the name XYZ in this case and the image while the second div contains the small red icons. I need to make them separate divs but still, keep them aligned as shown in the image below. Here is a link to my codepen.

[image: sample image]

Please help me solve this. Thanks.

https://codepen.io/danongu/pen/LYYevMv

HTML

```
<p>Team</p> </h2> <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <a class="black hover-none col-sm-12 m0Auto" href="/"><img class="club-image-border club-image-size m0Auto col-sm-12" src="http://www.cosmoleague.com/img/default-logo.png" alt="Team Logo"></a> </div>

<div class="currform">
<a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 2 - 1 Team">L</a><a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 0 - 2 Team">L</a><a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 0 - 1 Team">L</a><a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 3 - 0 Team">L</a><a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 0 - 2 Team">L</a>
</div>

CSS
@media all{a:active,a:hover{outline:0}
img{max-width:100%;height:auto;vertical-align:middle;border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic}
@media print{*{text-shadow:none!important;color:#000!important;background:0 0!important;box-shadow:none!important}
a,a:visited{text-decoration:underline}a[href]:after{content:" (" attr(href) ")"}
img{page-break-inside:avoid}img{max-width:100%!important}h2,p{orphans:3;widows:3}h2{page-break-after:avoid}}p{margin:0 0 11px}h2{margin:11px 0;font-family:inherit;font-weight:700;line-height:22px;color:inherit;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff}h2{font-size:32px;line-height:40px}h2 a:hover{text-decoration:none}@media print{a[href]:after{content:""}}@media (max-width:767px){h2{font-size:25.6px;line-height:25.6px}}}@media all{a:focus{outline:thin dotted #333;outline:thin auto grey;outline-offset:-2px}a{color:#5a5a5a;text-decoration:none}a:focus,a:hover{color:#343434;text-decoration:underline}}h2{font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;font-weight:inherit}h2{text-shadow:none}*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}img{height:auto}a{text-decoration:none}img{max-width:100%;height:auto}.form-icon.form-loss{background-color:#ef362a}.form-icon.form-loss:hover{background-color:#f27272}a{text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer}a.form-icon{margin:1px;display:inline-block}.form-icon{text-indent:0;background:0 0;border:0 solid transparent;border-radius:6px;color:#fff;line-height:15px;font-weight:700;font-size:10px;opacity:1;width:17px;text-align:center}@media screen and (max-width:700px){.form-icon{width:13.7px}}p{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}*{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;text-rendering:optimizelegibility;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.bold{font-weight:700}.ac{text-align:center!important}.bold{font-weight:700}a{text-decoration:none}a,div,h2,img,p{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}*{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;text-rendering:optimizelegibility;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}a:hover{text-decoration:underline}h2{font-size:1.8em;font-weight:700}.black,.black *{color:#222!important}.m0Auto{clear:both;display:block;margin:0 auto}.mt01e{margin-top:.1em!important}.bold{font-weight:700}.ac{text-align:center!important}.hover-none:hover{text-decoration:none!important}.bold{font-weight:700}.col-lg-4{width:33.333333%;float:left;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.club-image-border{border:1px solid #666;background:#fff;padding:.2em}.club-image-size{width:138px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}@media screen and (max-width:1000px){h2{font-size:1.4em}.col-sm-12{width:100%!important;max-width:100%!important}.col-sm-3{width:25%;max-width:25%;float:left}.h2h-team-intro h2{font-size:1em}.h2h-team-intro p{font-size:.9em}.black{color:#111!important}}img{vertical-align:text-bottom!important}
```

Comment: `body {display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center}` or on any other parent element of both divs, optionally you can add some `margin-top` on the `.currform` div

Comment: This seems to work but it's overwriting this `.col-lg-4{width:33.333333% ;float:left;  ` removing `align-items: center`  displaces the icons.

Comment: If you can add a wrapper/parent element then `.parent {max-width: 400px (for example); display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center}` where `max-width` can be the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

you should move the div contains little icons in to the div with class "h2h-team-intro" :

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3 h2h-team-intro">
    <h2 class="mt01e ac bold">
        <p>Team</p> 
    </h2> <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <a class="black hover-none col-sm-12 m0Auto" href="/">
     <img class="club-image-border club-image-size m0Auto col-sm-12" 
     src="http://www.cosmoleague.com/img/default-logo.png" alt="Team Logo">
    </a> 
    <div class="currform">
       <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 2 - 1 Team">L</a>
       <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 0 - 2 Team">L</a>
       <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 0 - 1 Team">L</a>
       <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 3 - 0 Team">L</a>
       <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Team 0 - 2 Team">L</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add this css:

```
.currform {
   text-align: center;
}
.currform > a.form-icon {
   // style your icon
}
```

and you dont need "&nbsp" for space. you can manage space with margin.

Comment: I need to close the first div to separate them. Like this ````<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3 h2h-team-intro">
    <h2 class="mt01e ac bold">
        <p>Team</p> 
    </h2> <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <a class="black hover-none col-sm-12 m0Auto" href="/">
     <img class="club-image-border club-image-size m0Auto col-sm-12" 
     src="http://www.cosmoleague.com/img/default-logo.png" alt="Team Logo">
    </a> </div>```` otherwise they will still be interdependent. Is this possible?

Comment: yes you can add this style:
 .currform {
       clear:both;
  }